# Using Windows Authenticated WCF services

Tags: wcf, wcf-security, windows-authentication

I have a Windows authenticated WCF service.

Using the following configuration:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;

binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
binding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
binding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);

NexumCrmServiceClient client = new NexumCrmServiceClient(binding, new EndpointAddress("http://xxxxxx:81/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.svc"));
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowNtlm = true;
//client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxx");
```

I'm getting this error:

> There was no endpoint listening at
>   http://xxxxxx:81/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.svc that could accept the message.
>   This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See
>   InnerException, if present, for more details...

And if I use the configuration below:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;

binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
binding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
binding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);

NexumCrmServiceClient client = new NexumCrmServiceClient(binding, new EndpointAddress("http://xxxxxx:81/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.svc"));
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowNtlm = true;
//client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxx");
```

I'm getting another error:

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme
>   'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was
>   'Negotiate,NTLM'.

Would you please suggest a configuration that works successfully?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please post your service configuration so an accurate answer can be provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you need to set:

```
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows
```

to get what your question title is referring to. Also, review this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648505.aspx) on using Windows authentication with basicHttpBinding.